# task only run when required directory folder is not available else it will skip that task

Tags: ansible

I need to install sqoop using ansible and move to /usr/lib but only when sqoop directory is not available in /tmp and /usr/lib

find the below code

```
---  
- name: Download Sqoop_1.4.7 Download on temp folder
  get_url:
    url: https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.7/sqoop-1.4.7.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp
    mode: 0777

- name: Extract Sqoop-1.4.7 into /tmp
  unarchive:
    remote_src: yes
    src: /tmp/sqoop-1.4.7.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp

- name: "check Sqoop direcotry is present in /tmp"
  stat: path=/tmp/sqoop-1.4.7
  register: p

- name: Move sqoop-1.4 directory
  when: not p.stat.exists
  command: mv /tmp/sqoop-1.4.7 /tmp/sqoop
  become: yes
  become_user: root

- name: "check Sqoop direcotry is present in /usr/lib/"
  shell: test "$(ls /usr/lib/sqoop)"
  register: sqooppresent
  changed_when: false

- name: Move sqoop-1.4 to /usr/lib/
  when: "sqooppresent.rc != 0"
  command: mv /tmp/sqoop /usr/lib/
  become: yes
  become_user: gaurav
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `stat` module to determine whether or not the path `/usr/lib/sqoop` exists.

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Only_if_a_file_exists_or_does_not_exist.html

```
- name: check if sqoop is present in /usr/lib/
  stat: 
    path: /usr/lib/sqoop
  register: sqooppresent

- name: Move sqoop-1.4 to /usr/lib/
  when: not sqooppresent.stat.exists
  command: mv /tmp/sqoop /usr/lib/
  become: yes
  become_user: gaurav
```